i'm using minus operation and case function but did not get answer
enter image description here
input  data:
table1   table2
id        id 
1         2
2         3
3         4
4         8
5         9
7         6       

output data:



id
status




1
not in table2


5
not in table2


7
not in table2


8
not in table1


9
not in table1


6
not in table1



i think using minus operator and case function in this table but i did not get answer. i don't know when use case function in this
sql:
select * from table1
minus 
select * from table2 
case when select * from table1
minus 
select * from table2 
then id
else not in table1
end as status


I'm afraid folks are going to have a hard time reading your sample data. Can you please format it in a manner that makes it clear what's in table1, what's in table2,  what output you're expecting, what query you actually used and what result you got?

what you want is a full outer join

You can use a FULL OUTER JOIN:
SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS id,
       NVL2(t1.id, 'Not in table2', 'Not in table1') AS status
FROM   table1 t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE  t1.id IS NULL
OR     t2.id IS NULL

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table1 (id) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL WHERE LEVEL != 6 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;

CREATE TABLE table2 (id) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL WHERE LEVEL NOT IN (1, 5, 7) CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9;

Outputs:



ID
STATUS




6
Not in table1


8
Not in table1


9
Not in table1


7
Not in table2


5
Not in table2


1
Not in table2



fiddle

What you want is a full outer join:
with table1 as (select id from (select level id from dual connect by level <=10) where id IN (1,2,3,4,5,7)),
     table2 as (select id from (select level id from dual connect by level <=10) where id IN (2,3,4,8,9,6))
select nvl(table1.id,table2.id) id,
       case when (table1.id is null) then 'not in table1'
            when (table2.id is null) then 'not in table2'
       end status
  from table1 full outer join table2 on table1.id = table2.id       
 where table1.id is null or table2.id is null


You can use various options; as you mentioned set operators, here's how:
Sample data:
SQL> with
  2  table1 (id) as
  3    (select 1 from dual union all
  4     select 2 from dual union all
  5     select 3 from dual union all
  6     select 4 from dual union all
  7     select 5 from dual union all
  8     select 7 from dual
  9    ),
 10  table2 (id) as
 11    (select 2 from dual union all
 12     select 3 from dual union all
 13     select 4 from dual union all
 14     select 8 from dual union all
 15     select 9 from dual union all
 16     select 6 from dual
 17    )

Query begins here:
 18  select a.id, 'not in table2' status from table1 a
 19  minus
 20  select b.id, 'not in table2'        from table2 b
 21  union
 22  select b.id, 'not in table1'        from table2 b
 23  minus
 24  select a.id, 'not in table1' status from table1 a;

        ID STATUS
---------- -------------
         7 not in table2
         5 not in table2
         1 not in table2
         6 not in table1
         9 not in table1
         8 not in table1

6 rows selected.

SQL>

